# Aggregating observations

Tags: r, dplyr

I have observations like this

```
    Id     Result    Comments
    1      45        Good
    1      12        
    1      33        
    2      33        Good
    2      43        
    2      10
```

I am trying to group these observations by Id , to produce an output as shown below

```
    Id      Comments
    1       Good
    2       Good
```

Need help

Comment: @Metrics :) i am what should I pass for the parameter FUN ?

Comment: What do you want to compute? mean,length, sd, and so on. What are those comments column?

Comment: @Metrics, I dont want any mean or any statistics just Id and Comments for each id, I tried using aggregate I got an error , argument "FUN" is missing, not sure if aggregate is appropriate ?

Comment: If the comment is always in the first row for each group, would `aggregate(Comments ~ Id, data=dat, FUN=head,1)` suffice? Or if you just want the first non-blank comment in each group, maybe: `aggregate(Comments ~ Id, data=dat, FUN=function(x) x[x!=""][1])`

Comment: @thelatemail , thats exactly what the doctor ordered :)

Comment: @BridgeportTuckerJr  If there is only one non-missing Comments per 'Id', you could try `df[df$Comments!='', -2]`